# WP7 Datepicker page - custom background

Tags: windows-phone-7, datepicker

I want to use the WP7 toolkit datepicker and have my own custom background on the picker page.  There are several examples that show  the use of  a  custom page to replace  the existing selection mechanism  e.g. http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-datepicker-and-timepicker-in-depth--api-and-customization

But I don't want to do that - I simply want the picker page to have a different background (than the themed white or black)  Can I do this easily. Or do I have to download the toolkit code and include that in my solution and adjust that?

Comment: You can use sources, but you don't need to include the whole toolkit, only several files used by `DatePicker`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that you will have to create a copy of the [DatePickerPage.xaml](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/74775#1510210) file from the Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit in your application, change it to meet your requirements, and then on your DatePicker control set the PickerPageUri proprety to the new DatePickerPage.xaml

Comment: So I can do this rather than have to import and build the whole toolkit project?  Thanks

Comment: Exactly! Please do mark as replyed if this answers the question!

Comment: I tried this solution for normal listpicker. It seems that it does not work. The new page opens BUT the no items are binded to that page.. it just opens a blank page.